# How to match a newline character in a raw string?

Tags: python, regex, python-re, rawstring

I got a little confused about Python raw string. I know that if we use raw string, then it will treat `'\'` as a normal backslash (ex. `r'\n'` would be `\` and `n`). However, I was wondering what if I want to match a new line character in raw string. I tried `r'\\n'`, but it didn't work.

Anybody has some good idea about this?

Comment: What kind of match are we talking about here?  Are you talking about a regular expression match, or simply a `if ... in my_raw_string`?

Comment: Sorry to confuse you. I'm talking about a regular expression.

Comment: A raw string (really a raw string **literall**) is **not a different kind of string**; it is **only** a different way to *describe* the string in source code. The problem is simply "how do I match a newline character in a string using regex?"; that has **nothing to do with** raw strings.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

In a regular expression, you need to specify that you're in multiline mode:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = """cat
... dog"""
>>> 
>>> re.match(r'cat\ndog',s,re.M)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0xcb7c8>
```

Notice that `re` translates the `\n` (raw string) into newline.  As you indicated in your comments, you don't actually **need** [`re.M`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.M) for it to match, but it does help with matching `$` and `^` more intuitively:

```
>> re.match(r'^cat\ndog',s).group(0)
'cat\ndog'
>>> re.match(r'^cat$\ndog',s).group(0)  #doesn't match
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
>>> re.match(r'^cat$\ndog',s,re.M).group(0) #matches.
'cat\ndog'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @mgilson ! I'd also like to know why we need to specify multiline mode. I tried matching without it, like this "re.match(r'cat\ndog', s)" and it still works.

Comment: @user1783403 -- You're correct.  I should read the documentation more.  specifying `re.M` gets `^` and `$` to match more intuitively.

Comment: Any way to get `$` to match "less intuitively" - i.e. to match *only* at the end of the string? I don't want it to match before `\n`

Comment: Use re.DOTALL option to match `\n`.

Answer (score 16):

The simplest answer is to simply not use a raw string. You can escape backslashes by using `\\`.

If you have huge numbers of backslashes in some segments, then you could concatenate raw strings and normal strings as needed:

```
r"some string \ with \ backslashes" "\n"
```

(Python automatically concatenates string literals with only whitespace between them.)

Remember if you are working with paths on Windows, the easiest option is to just use forward slashes - it will still work fine.

Comment: @mgilson I was just checking it worked with raw strings and normal strings, as it's not something I had done. Edited as it does. It's actually a little better as I believe the concatenation is done at parse time, rather than when it's executed.

Comment: Yeah, I'd never actually checked before now either :)

Comment: I'm not sure about the downvote either.  I suppose somebody might have seen the comment about OP wanting this in the context of a regex and decided that this didn't apply.  Anyway, FWIW, I upvoted because I liked the automagic concatenation of strings (raw and normal)

Comment: Yeah, with that information, the post is a little out, but that wasn't there when I posted. Ah well, unexplained downvotes happen.

Answer (score 3):

Ten years on, this came up in my search for newline not matching.

There are a couple of options. Each targeting different angles.
This answer revolves around applicable regex flag.

1. Raw string at Source
2. regex match and flag
3. **regex flag**: `re.DOTALL`

---

1. Raw string at source:
   If it does not have 'impact' on the 'meaning' or context of the text, the newline, \n, can be replaced or stripped off. For instance, to strip off, one can use replace(), strip(), sub(), search() or any option/preference.
2. regex match and flag
   Regex can be done in-place, wrapping around the newline:
   Regex can be out-place, matching anywhere within the text irrespective of the newline, \n.
3. regex flag: `re.DOTALL` , `re.MULTILINE | re.M`
   The Python manual documents the `re.DOTALL` flag to 'extend' `.` pattern to also match newline. In my view, the `.DOTALL` handles the newline `\n` much better. It appears it allows multiple strings to be matches 'easily'. See sample code.

> re.DOTALL [https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.DOTALL]
> Make the '.' special character match any character at all, including a newline; without this flag, '.' will match anything except a newline. Corresponds to the inline flag (?s).

> (Dot.)
> In the default mode, this matches any character except a newline. If the DOTALL flag has been specified, this matches any character including a newline.

> ^
> (Caret.) Matches the start of the string, and in MULTILINE mode also matches immediately after each newline.

> $
> Matches the end of the string or just before the newline at the end of the string, and in MULTILINE mode also matches before a newline.
> Kindly note that in MULTILINE mode, `match()` only matches at the beginning of the string, whereas using `search()` with a regular expression beginning with '`^`' will match at the beginning of each line. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#search-vs-match

Below is a Python walkthrough of `.DOTALL` vis-a-vis `.M`

```py
import re

## raw string
s1_str = '''"type": "Car",
  "brand": "Ford",
  "model": "Fiesta",
  "colour": "Black'''

s2_str = '"Type": "Car",\n"brand": "Ford", \n"model": "Fiesta", \n"colour": "Black'

##regex match 
m1_1 = re.match(r'(?=.*?[cC])(?=.*?Fiesta).*', s1_str, re.DOTALL)  #matches!!
m1_2 = re.match(r'(?=^.*?[cC]).*?$', s1_str, re.M)    #matches!!
m2_1 = re.match(r'(?=.*[cC]ar)(?=.*Fiesta).*', s2_str, re.DOTALL)  #matches
m2_2 = re.match(r'(?=.*[cC]ar)(?=.*Fiesta).*', s2_str, re.M)  #doesn't match
m2_3 = re.match(r'(?=.*[cC]ar)(?=.*brand).*', s2_str, re.DOTALL)  #matches
m2_4 = re.match(r'(?=.*[cC]ar)(?=.*brand).*', s2_str, re.M)  #doesn't match
m2_5 = re.match(r'.*Car",\n"brand":', s2_str, re.DOTALL)  #matches
m2_6 = re.match(r'.*Car",$\n"brand', s2_str) #doesn't match
m2_7 = re.match(r'.*Car",$\n"brand', s2_str, re.M)  #matches
m2_8 = re.match(r'.*Car",$\n"brand', s2_str, re.DOTALL)  #doesn't matches
m2_9 = re.match(r'.*Car.*\n"brand', s2_str, re.DOTALL)  #matches  #.group

match_list = [m1_1, m1_2, m2_1, m2_2, m2_3, m2_4, m2_5, m2_6, m2_7, m2_8, m2_9]
print('matches: \nm1_1| {0} \nm1_2| {1} \nm2_1| {2} \nm2_2| {3} \nm2_3| {4} \nm2_4| {5} \nm2_5| {6} \nm2_6| {7} \nm2_7| {8} \nm2_8| {9} \nm2_9| {10}'.format(*match_list))
```

[output]

```py
matches: 
m1_1| <re.Match object; span=(0, 73), match='"type": "Car",\n  "brand": "Ford",\n  "model": "F> 
m1_2| <re.Match object; span=(0, 14), match='"type": "Car",'> 
m2_1| <re.Match object; span=(0, 69), match='"Type": "Car",\n"brand": "Ford", \n"model": "Fies> 
m2_2| None 
m2_3| <re.Match object; span=(0, 69), match='"Type": "Car",\n"brand": "Ford", \n"model": "Fies> 
m2_4| None 
m2_5| <re.Match object; span=(0, 23), match='"Type": "Car",\n"brand":'> 
m2_6| None 
m2_7| <re.Match object; span=(0, 21), match='"Type": "Car",\n"brand'> 
m2_8| None 
m2_9| <re.Match object; span=(0, 21), match='"Type": "Car",\n"brand'>
```

[UPDATED]
I've taken note of interesting posts on regex flag

- [diff btw re.DOTALL and re.MULTILINE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41620093/whats-the-difference-between-re-dotall-and-re-multiline)
- [Match DOTALL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25328558/how-to-match-anything-dotall-without-dotall)

Answer (score 2):

you also can use [\r\n] for matching to new line

Comment: to match \r\n, I do like this
[\r][\n]

within [ ] the escape looses meaning for re module.

Answer (score 0):

```
def clean_with_puncutation(text):    
    from string import punctuation
    import re
    punctuation_token={p:'<PUNC_'+p+'>' for p in punctuation}
    punctuation_token['<br/>']="<TOKEN_BL>"
    punctuation_token['\n']="<TOKEN_NL>"
    punctuation_token['<EOF>']='<TOKEN_EOF>'
    punctuation_token['<SOF>']='<TOKEN_SOF>'
  #punctuation_token



    regex = r"(<br/>)|(<EOF>)|(<SOF>)|[\n\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\[\]\
           {\}\;\:\,\.\/\?\|\`\_\\+\\\=\~\-\<\>]"

###Always put new sequence token at front to avoid overlapping results
 #text = '<EOF>!@#$%^&*()[]{};:,./<>?\|`~-= _+\<br/>\n <SOF>\ '
    text_=""

    matches = re.finditer(regex, text)

    index=0

    for match in matches:
     #print(match.group())
     #print(punctuation_token[match.group()])
     #print ("Match at index: %s, %s" % (match.start(), match.end()))
        text_=text_+ text[index:match.start()] +" " 
              +punctuation_token[match.group()]+ " "
        index=match.end()
    return text_
```