# How to match anything (DOTALL) without DOTALL?

Tags: python, regex

My regexp needs both the default non-newline-matching dot and the `re.DOTALL` dot (`.` matches newline). I need several of the former and just *one* of the latter within a single regexp. Nevertheless, because I need one dot to match newlines, I have to use `DOTALL`, and use `[^\n]` several times to get the default "anything except newlines" behavior.

I'd like to get rid of the `DOTALL`, replace those `[^\n]` with `.` and have a more complicated way of matching "anything including newlines" in the one place that I need.

So the question is: what is the regexp syntax to match "anything including newline" without `DOTALL`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I always use `r"[\s\S]"` all whitespace and non-whitespace, so everything.

Answer (score 7):

> match "anything including newline" without DOTALL?

You can try with [Character Classes or Character Sets](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)

```
[\s\S]+
```