# What's the difference between re.DOTALL and re.MULTILINE?

Tags: python, regex

When matching an expression on multiple lines, I always used `re.DOTALL` and it worked OK. Now I stumbled across the `re.MULTILINE` string, and it looks like it's doing the same thing.

From the `re` module (doesn't make it clearer, but the values are different):

```
M = MULTILINE = sre_compile.SRE_FLAG_MULTILINE # make anchors look for newline
S = DOTALL = sre_compile.SRE_FLAG_DOTALL # make dot match newline

SRE_FLAG_MULTILINE = 8 # treat target as multiline string
SRE_FLAG_DOTALL = 16 # treat target as a single string
```

So is there a difference in the usage, and what is the subtle cases where it could return something different?

Comment: I'm glad there is this python specific question. The supposed "duplicate" was not helpful for me.

Comment: thanks! all things considered I'm leaving it closed. Once Martjin has answered there's no need to add anything :) being closed as duplicate isn't necessarily bad, and in that case, it allowed you to find the question & get your answer, so it is useful.

Comment: but I undeleted it, because I feel that the title keywords are useful for future users (check above comment :))

Answer (score 47, accepted):

They are quite different. Yes, both affect how newlines are treated, but they switch behaviour for different concepts.

- `re.MULTILINE` affects where `^` and `$` *anchors* match.

  Without the switch, `^` and `$` match only at the start and end, respectively, of the *whole text*. With the switch, they also match just before or after a newline:

  ```
  >>> import re
  >>> re.search('foo$', 'foo\nbar') is None  # no match
  True
  >>> re.search('foo$', 'foo\nbar', flags=re.MULTILINE)
  <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 3), match='foo'>
  ```
- `re.DOTALL` affects what the `.` *pattern* can match.

  Without the switch, `.` matches any character *except a newline*. With the switch, newlines are matched as well:

  ```
  >>> re.search('foo.', 'foo\nbar') is None  # no match
  True
  >>> re.search('foo.', 'foo\nbar', flags=re.DOTALL)
  <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 4), match='foo\n'>
  ```

Comment: FYI for those reading this: negated character classes like `r'[^x]'` seem to match newlines **whether or not** dotall is set! e.g. while `re.match(r'.*', 'abc\n123')` only nabs the first line without dotall, `re.match(r'[^4]*', 'abc\n123')` nabs the whole string

Comment: @JamesTheAwesomeDude: that's entirely to be expected, because `[^x]` is not the `.` pattern. `DOTALL` only changes how `.` works, not negated character classes. You can always add `\n` to the negated class: `[^x\n]`.

Answer (score 6):

It is not doing the same thing, `DOTALL` matches the newline character as well, while `MULTILINE` enables `^` and `$` to work on every line.

Example:

```
The quick brown fox 
jumps over the lazy dog.
```

Here, `.+` would yield two results (the first and the second line) with no `DOTALL` mode. If `DOTALL` is turned on, it matches the whole phrase.

```
The quick brown fox 
jumps over the lazy dog.
```

Here, ie `^\w+` with `MULTILINE` mode on, will match twice as there's a *word character*  at the start of **every** line.