# Newbie in regex patterns. How to capture multiple lines?

Tags: python, regex

Im quite new to regex patterns. Im having difficulty parsing a text file and returning the matches per paragraph. So basically every paragraph is unique.

Here is my example text file

```
A quick brown
fox jumps over
the lazy dog;
1234;

Here is
the second paragraph
123141
```

I want is matches[0] to be:
#A quick brown
fox jumps over
the lazy dog;
1234;

matches[1] to be:
#Here is
the second paragraph
123141

I've tried

```
regex = re.compile(r"(.*\n)\n", re.MULTILINE)
   with open(file_dir, "r") as file:
      matches = regex.findall(file.read())
print matches
```

But the result is ['1234;\n']. It doesnt capture the whole paragraph, and it didnt capture the second as well. What is the most efficient way of doing this?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41620093/whats-the-difference-between-re-dotall-and-re-multiline

Comment: What do you want actually? **So basically every paragraph is unique** Is it the separator? Kindly give a more generic input file details without comments

Answer (score 2):

Try `(\S[\s\S]*?)(?:\n\n|$)`:

1. `\S` Matches a non-whitespace character
2. `[\s\S]*?` Match 0 or more whitespace or non-whitespace characters, i.e. any type of character including newline non-greedily. Items 1 and 2 are in capture group 1.
3. `(?:\n\n|$)` Matches two successive newline characters or $ (which matches either the end of string or the newline before the end of string) in a non-capture group.

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/C3UJXp/2/)

The code:

```
import re

s = """A quick brown
fox jumps over
the lazy dog;
1234;

Here is
the second paragraph
123141"""

matches = re.findall(r'(\S[\s\S]*?)(?:\n\n|$)', s)
print(matches)
```

Prints:

```
['A quick brown\nfox jumps over\nthe lazy dog;\n1234;', 'Here is\nthe second paragraph\n123141']
```

Alternatively, you can use:

```
\S(?:(?!\n\n)[\s\S])*
```

Which uses a negative looahead assertion and has about the same cost as the previous regex. This regex first looks for a non-whitespace character and then as long as the following input stream does not contain two successive newline characters will continue to scan one more character.

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/WAAqie/1/)

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. I think the reason I was having a hard time creating a regex expression was because of using the multi line function. Although your second answer works as well in multiline.

Comment: You might be able to get away with using multiline with the second regex version, but it is irrelevant because there is no `^` or `$` being used in the pattern, which is what re.MULTILINE affects. In the first regex `re.MULTILINE` would definitely be an error.

Answer (score -1):

This is a good start :

```
(?:.+\s)+
```

Test it [here](https://regex101.com/r/iTSKXu/1)

Test code:

```
import re

regex = r"(?:.+\s)+"

test_str = ("A quick brown\n"
    "fox jumps over\n"
    "the lazy dog;\n"
    "1234;\n\n"
    "Here is\n"
    "the second paragraph\n"
    "123141")

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):
    
    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))
    
    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1
        
        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))
```

Output:

```
Match 1 was found at 0-49: A quick brown
fox jumps over
the lazy dog;
1234;

Match 2 was found at 50-79: Here is
the second paragraph
```

You can see that the last line of the last paragraph is truncated. To avoid this, before matching the regex, add a `\n` at the end of the string, so the regex can detect the end of the paragraph:
`test_str += '\n'`

You can try it [here](https://tio.run/##dVDBTsJAED3br5j0tBtqY4UThhgPRkmAk95IzEqHUqW7dXYrIOm31@2WtsTgHjZv35u382byg9koOayqNMsVGSD0PMIE9zAB8tn9OBwsNR/4nmdQmzdtyArMf4CvIl19wjupnVxK37vy12oPH0WWa1DfSA1nNghb8XOAWCV3DRXdDkcWNo9nJIRU98UaV0rGkAsSCYl803miUeRzz8uEWW1Q1@EwXKcyTg0Sc4EDaBMGtTh/nb1MZ9PFo3WtFYFzLoosaBCkElAWGZIwyE7fBqCNIDOJ@NgDe9yVUyqNHXnubMf2nxJ2QsNaFTauMHB0zvL6iDIux6ey0g9tawtZ67LB@yDO0jKhezEe2FhxR1pcU03klkxIFTnjnPch6wkdXfewo5GQCbKbALYo2ZlL17ZmuPp0lkkPBxB1egfaJTzVVXBsi8v/F@BK@gVc6HR5Aa16YRFnkoN/FtLJnFfVLw) without the `\n` at the end, and [here](https://tio.run/##dVDBTsJAED3br5j0tBtqY4UThhgPRkmAk95IzEqHUqW7dXYrIOm31@2WtsTgHjZv35u382byg9koOayqNMsVGSD0PMIE9zAB8tn9OBwsNR/4nmdQmzdtyArMf4CvIl19wjupnVxK37vy12oPH0WWa1DfSA1nNghb8XOAWCV3DRXdDkcWNo9nJIRU98UaV0rGkAsSCYl803miUWQx97xMmNUGdR0Pw3Uq49QgMRc5gDZjUIvz19nLdDZdPFrXWhE456LIggZBKgFlkSEJg@z0bQDaCDKTiI89sMddOaXS2KHnznZs/ylhJzSsVWEDCwNH5yyvjyjjcnwqK/3QtraQtS4bvA/iLC0TuhfjgY0Vd6TFNdVEbsmEVJEzznkfsp7Q0XUPOxoJmSC7CWCLkp25dG1rhqtPZ5n0cABRp3egXcJTXQXHtrj8fwGupF/AhU6XF9CqFxZxJjn4ZyGdzHlV/QI) with it.

Comment: No, the code is generated from [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/iTSKXu/1), which I used to create the regex examples and python code.

Comment: Go to the "generated code" section, you'll have access to multiple programing languages, that you can test on tio.run