# Python pattern matching with 'r' prefix

Tags: python

Suppose I have the following code (taken from Google's Python Class) which assists with pattern matching by checking if a piece of regex lies within a text

```
def Find(pat, text):
    match=re.search(pat,text)
    if match: print (match.group())
    else: print('not found')
```

When I run `Find(r'\n', '\\n')`, the function returns `not found`.

From my understanding, the `r` in `r'\n'` removes the special meaning from the newline character, meaning that `r'\n'` and `'\\n'` are essentially identical strings. Why then, does the above function return `not found`?

Comment: Funny enough `Find(r'\n', '\n')` is found

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to match a new line character in Python raw string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14689531/how-to-match-a-new-line-character-in-python-raw-string)

Comment: The regular expression `\n` still matches a literal newline, not a literal backslash and a literal `n`. You need two backslashes in the expression which reaches the regex engine, so `r'\\n'` or `'\\\\n'` (sic)